# BS Chemistry Thesis Topic Suggestions in the Areas of Natural Products, Synthetic Inorganic and Organometallic Chemistry, Physical Chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I am a 3rd year Chemistry student. In partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree Bachelor of Science in Chemistry, we are to present an undergraduate thesis. We were highly encouraged to choose a topic that interests us, however, I find it difficult to find a topic because my interests are too broad. I also want my undergraduate thesis to be publishable internationally but I don’t know what topics would top that. I’ve had a difficult time finding topics that are relevant, unique, cost-effective, and feasible for an undergraduate that interests me. Can you suggest thesis topics in the areas of natural products, synthetic inorganic and organometallic synthesis, or physical chemistry? We are given 10 months to propose, experiment, and defend our thesis. Thank you.

Comment: Huh, while you may be encouraged to do that, I don't see how it's a good idea. Try finding a good supervisor and talk what the topic could be. More importantly you question isn't suitable for the site, as it's got no specific answer.

Answer (score -3):

Here is one problem that could be studied in an undergraduate thesis : the kinetics of copper dissolution. I explain. If you put always the same copper cylinder in always the same volume of different concentrations of sulfuric acid, and if you introduce a rubber tubing producing constant bubbling of air into this solution, you will observe that the solution gets slowly more blue. You could measure the concentration of copper by a colorimeter. The strange thing is that there is no corrosion of copper in highly diluted solutions, and in high concentrations of sulfuric acid. Why ? I don't know. The corrosion is maximum for a given intermediate concentration. Which one ? I don't know, You may study many different solutions simultaneously by using as many beakers and as many pumps as needed. Another strange phenomena : when the solution gets saturated in copper sulfate, the corrosion does not stop. It continues, and well crystallized copper sulfate is slowly developing on the copper cylinder. You may weigh this amount of cristal versus time. Try ! It is easy. In my opinion, it has not been studied so far. I may be wrong,

Comment: Maybe you want to post this as a question instead?

Comment: Why do people decide to disqualify the strange facts I am mentioning ? I will not  post this strange behavior as a question now, as suggested by Buck Thorn. I have not enough measurements. It would be better to repeat this experiment, with a lot to different concentrations. I have done it with only four solutions.  It should be repeated and the kinetics seriously determined. It could be a nice subject fo an undergraduate thesis.

Comment: As you are probably aware by now, questions such as in this post tend to be considered off-topic as "opinion-based" (well, here is was voted "unfocused"), and answers are sometimes discouraged with downvotes.